# Use dropdown to select objects and use reuse variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a select dropdown to change data sets used elsewhere in my code, but I can't figure out how to make the switch... I tried changing the var master to the value of the option selected, but I can't get this to work!

The end result I am trying to achieve is to be able to reuse the variable 'master' to insert different datasets into a chart - based on the selection.

For instance - I want all of the references to 'master' to be updated with the data from the selected dataset.

HTML

```
     <select id='chart-selector' name='chart-selector'>
        <option value='pre2010All'>Total Installations</option>
        <option value='pre2010Res'>Residential</option>
        <option value='pre2010NonRes'>Non Residential</option>
        <option value='pre2010Util'>Utiltiy</option>
     </select>
```

JS

```
      var master = [];

      $('select[name="chart-selector"]').change(function(){             
            master = $(this).val();
            console.log('Data Set:' +master.CA);
      });     


    // Pre 2010 //
    var pre2010All = {CA:"88901", AZ:"48420", ID:"53868", NY:"2322"};
    var pre2010Res = {CA:"2", AZ:"4", ID:"5", NY:"6"};
    var pre2010NonRes = {CA:"56", AZ:"34", ID:"45", NY:"36"};
    var pre2010Util = {CA:"16", AZ:"14", ID:"15", NY:"16"};

    // 2010 //
    var Y_2010All = {CA:"82901", AZ:"49420", ID:"56868", NY:"2822"};
    var Y_2010Res = {CA:"5", AZ:"7", ID:"5", NY:"8"};
    var Y_2010NonRes = {CA:"56", AZ:"38", ID:"49", NY:"37"};
    var Y_2010Util = {CA:"17", AZ:"17", ID:"15", NY:"18"};
```

Answer (score 4):

`master` is just a string, it's not treated as the name of another variable. Whenever you think you need dynamic variables, use an object whose keys are the names.

```
const datasets = {
    // Pre 2010 //
    pre2010All: {CA:"88901", AZ:"48420", ID:"53868", NY:"2322"},
    pre2010Res: {CA:"2", AZ:"4", ID:"5", NY:"6"},
    pre2010NonRes: {CA:"56", AZ:"34", ID:"45", NY:"36"},
    pre2010Util: {CA:"16", AZ:"14", ID:"15", NY:"16"},

    // 2010 //
    Y_2010All: {CA:"82901", AZ:"49420", ID:"56868", NY:"2822"},
    Y_2010Res: {CA:"5", AZ:"7", ID:"5", NY:"8"},
    Y_2010NonRes: {CA:"56", AZ:"38", ID:"49", NY:"37"},
    Y_2010Util: {CA:"17", AZ:"17", ID:"15", NY:"18"}
};
```

Then you can do

```
console.log("Dataset:" + datasets[master].CA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an object for your data?

```
var type;

$('select[name="chart-selector"]').change(function(){             
      type = $(this).val();
      console.log('Data Set:' + data[type].CA);
});     

data = {};
// Pre 2010 //
data.pre2010All = {CA:"88901", AZ:"48420", ID:"53868", NY:"2322"};
data.pre2010Res = {CA:"2", AZ:"4", ID:"5", NY:"6"};
data.pre2010NonRes = {CA:"56", AZ:"34", ID:"45", NY:"36"};
data.pre2010Util = {CA:"16", AZ:"14", ID:"15", NY:"16"};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all things to reference master and it not change then you cannot do this:

```
master = $(this).val();
```

This causes master to point to a different memory address for the different value.  If you want it to always stay the same, then you would want to do something like.

```
master.splice(0, master.length).push($(this).val());
```

This removes all the elements from the array, and then pushes the new value to it.  The point here is that the memory address for the array that master points to never changes.  Only the values in the array.